# Can I make Visual Studio place curly braces on the same line as an if statement (in HTML)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, view, formatting, curly-braces

In Visual Studio while designing MVC views (in `.aspx` or `.ascx` files), I often use `if` statements. When I auto-format (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>), Visual Studio wraps the braces in this really ugly and hard to read way:

```
<% if (Model.UserIsAuthenticated)
    { %>
       (some HTML goes here...)
<% } %>
```

Is there any way to make Visual Studio auto-format like this instead:

```cs
<% if (Model.UserIsAuthenticated) { %>
       (some HTML goes here...)
<% } %>
```

Or is there a better way to do this? I don't want to use Razor quite yet, but it looks like it would solve my problem. I'm using VS2010 with Resharper 5, if that helps.

Answer (score 130):

Under <kbd>Tools</kbd> → <kbd>Options</kbd> → <kbd>Text Editor</kbd> → <kbd>C#</kbd> → <kbd>Formatting</kbd> → <kbd>New Lines</kbd> are the rules for the open brace on each case (new methods, control blocks, etc), maybe you can find the one you want there.

[image]

Comment: That works for .cs files, but I'd like to only have this type of formatting for C# *within* a view page.

Comment: It worked for me on a View Page. I unchecked "Place open brace on new line for control blocks", try that one.

Comment: Right, it works on a view file, but then it also applies to all of the cs files. I'm trying to get it to only apply to the view files.

Comment: Just point out if you are using resharper: RESHARPER->options..->c#->Formatting Style->Braces Layout change from BSD to K&R style

Comment: it shows me an error : "An error occurred loading this property page". What should I do, I have VS 2013 unlimited.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i was looking for +1

Comment: In my version it is C# -> Code Style -> Formatting -> New Lines

Answer (score 11):

The menu has changed a bit with VS2019.

You can find formatting options by going into
<kbd>Tools</kbd> → <kbd>Options</kbd> → <kbd>Text Editor</kbd> → <kbd>C#</kbd> → <kbd>Code Style</kbd> → <kbd>Formatting</kbd> → <kbd>NewLines</kbd>

[image: Formatting options in Visual Stusio 2019]

Comment: Thank you for showing the plethora of options. I still never understood why VS don't just have *one* option to control all of those and the entire convention.

Answer (score 3):

In extension to [Fleix Martinez's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4020087/8164116) answer:

In mac, **2020 Visual Studio**, this is how it is done:

`Preferences` -> `Source Code` -> `Code Formatting` -> `C# Source Code` -> select `C# Format` tab

1. Press `Edit`
   [image]
2. Select `New Lines` from `Category`
3. Uncheck all these(choose at your will):
   [image]

Answer (score -1):

the formatting is handled by individual plugins, for js you can use the following setting:

```
// Defines whether an open brace is put onto a new line for functions or not.
"javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true,
```

Comment: Wrong software, buddy. This isn't Visual Studio Code.