# Easy way to compare values of more than 3 variables?

Tags: c#, comparison

I want to check whether these variables have same values.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
int a = 5;
int b = 5;
int c = 5;
int d = 5;
int e = 5;
. . .
int k = 5;

if(a==b && b==c && c==d && d==e && .... && j==k)  
{
   //this is Complex way and not well understandable.
}
```

Any easy way to Compare all are same?
**LIKE in below example**

```
if(a==b==c==d==e.....j==k)
{
    //Understandable but not work 
}
```

Comment: If (a + b + c .... + k != 55) ... :)

Comment: Oh noes!  a = 55, b = 0, ..., k = 0 :)

Comment: @ithcy, 5 is just an example it may be 2 or 3 or some other value depends upon user.

Comment: So these are not in any kind of collection (eg: list or array); just tons of plain variables?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

how about something like this:

```
if (Array.TrueForAll<int>(new int[] {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k },
        val => (a == val))) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could create a var args method to do that:

```
bool intsEqual (params int[] ints) { 
   for (int i = 0; i < ints.Length - 1; i++) {
       if (ints[i] != ints[i+1]) {
          return False;
       }
   }
   return True;
}
```

Then just call it with all your ints as parameters:

```
if (intsEqual(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k)) {
    doSomeStuff();
}
```

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be ints.Length and i < ints.Length - 1?

Comment: Yeah probably, I almost never use C#.

Comment: The second one is off-by-1 error and it is nothing to do with c# :)

Comment: LOL, this is true.  I actually create methods like this quite a bit, mostly for convenience methods in test cases.  But it's always in Java or Groovy, so I'm not used to this crazy .NET syntax.

Comment: @Kaleb: crazy .NET syntax?!?  Wanna fight about it? :)

Comment: You bet!  I'm always willing to defend the opening braces on same line (and Steve Mcconnell will back me up)!!  LOL.  At least we don't have an end statement like Ruby.

Comment: @Kaleb: For the record, VS supports opening braces on the same line as well, you just have to modify the setting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020070/can-i-make-visual-studio-place-curly-braces-on-the-same-line-as-an-if-statement.

Answer (score 4):

With this many variables, would it make sense to move them into an array?

You could then test to see if they are all equal using Linq expressions like `myarray.Distinct().Count() == 1;` or perhaps `myarray.All(r => r == 5);`

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought, but if you can calculate the standard deviation of the entire list, and it is equal to zero, you would have your answer.

Here's an answer on the site that addresses this that may help with that:  [Standard deviation of generic list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141692/c-standard-deviation-of-generic-list)

Interesting problem.  Good luck with it.

Comment: Yay, nothing like increasing defficiency.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the easiest way is to place them all into a list and then use the following to compare. This is in essence looping through and comparing to the first value, but this is a little cleaner.

```
var match = counts.All(x => x == counts[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
int common = a;
if (a==common && b==common  && c==common  && d==common  && .... && k==common)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a helper method like this:

```
public static bool AllEqual<T> (params T[] values) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    if (values.Length < 2) return true;

    for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
        if (!values[i].Equals (values[0])) return false;

    return true;    
}
```

This will be subtly different to the == operator in special cases, though:

```
AllEqual (double.NaN, double.NaN).Dump();    // True
(double.NaN == double.NaN).Dump();           // False
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because a==b evaluates to a boolean which can't be compared to an integer, c. What you have seems to be the best way.

Comment: I know that, just given an example to explain what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider putting the values in an array and using a for() loop.  It isn't really any simpler, but it might help if the number of values changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable argument helper function to perform the comparison pretty easily.

```
static bool CompareLongList(params int[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length > 1)
        {
            int value = args[0];

            for (int i = 1; i < args.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (value != args[i])
                    return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Then you would just use the function as follows

```
if(CompareLongList(a,b,c,d,e,f,j,h,i,j,k))
{
   // True Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question I came across but I was wondering what's wrong with:

```
if (a == (b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & j & k))
{

}
```

Comment: nothing if you are ok with checking if a is equal to the value of all those letters anded together.

Comment: @user3303020, are you sure. Won't b & c = 0b0000? We are doing an AND operation and not an OR.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the same elements in array:

```
same = len(uniq([1,2,3,4])) == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq Query.
var greatestInt = new List() { a,b,c,d,e,f}.Max();

Comment: but he wanted to know if they are all the same... not which one is the greatest

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise and is a possible way to check multiple variables for same value.
Such a helper method could of course also check for equality instead of using the '&' operator. Helper method accepting a params array of variables seems to be the right method here. We could adjust this method to accept a generic argument also, but there are only a few data types which support boolean logical operators anyways in C# (and other languages).

Testing with a high value of Int32 to check validity of this:

```
void Main()
{
    int a = 1234567891;
    int b = 1234567891;
    int c = 1234567891; 
    int d = 1234567891;
    int e = 1234567891; 
    int f = 1234567891; 
    int g = 1234567891; 
    int h = 1234567891; 
    int i = 1234567891; 
    int j = 1234567891;
    int k = 1234567891; 
    bool areAllSameValue = IntUtils.AreAllVariablesSameValue(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k);
    areAllSameValue.Dump(); //Linqpad method - dump this code into Linqpad to test
}

public class IntUtils
{
    public static bool AreAllVariablesSameValue(params int[] values)
    {
        if (values == null || !values.Any())
        {
            return false;
        }
        int bitWiseAndValue = values[0];
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            bitWiseAndValue &= value;
        }
        return bitWiseAndValue == values[0];        
    }
}
```

This spots also if one of the values got a different sign (negative number).